# Javascript- print out options from select menus

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a javascript project that requires me to dynamically generate three drop down menus. I currently have everything working, but their is one last feature I don't know how to implement.

How do I print out the user's choices of the options they made from the select menu? For example, if the user chose food, fruit, and watermelon, I would print out "You choose food, which is a fruit, and you like watermelon." Something along those lines. How would I print out the choices the users made if the other two select menus were dynamically generated?

Edit: I cannot use jquery or innerHTML for this project.

Comment: here's jfiddle for anyone who wants to help: http://jsfiddle.net/wL32Z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value from JS. Then create a label node add the text to it and append the label to some page element

```
var comicCompanySelect = document.getElementById("myCompanies");
var comicValue=comicCompanySelect.options[comicCompanySelect.selectedIndex].value;

var comicTeamSelect=document.getElementById("myTeams");
var teamValue=comicTeamSelect.options[comicTeamSelect.selectedIndex].value;

var myHeroesSelect=document.getElementById("myHeroes");
var heroesValue=myHeroesSelect.options[myHeroesSelect.selectedIndex].value;

 var label=document.createElement("label");
 var outputText=document.createTextNode("You choose "+comicValue+", which is a"+teamValue+", and you like"+heroesValue);
 label.appendChild(outputText);

 element.appendChild(label); //append it to desired element on page
```

If you want to display text instead of value use **.text** instead of **.value**

Comment: in this case, is "element" name of the div the form is contained in?

Comment: Its not the name, its element like div itslef. If you want to put it into div,identified by name or id use document.getElementsByName("divName")[0].appendChild(label) or document.getElementById('divId').appendChild(label)

Comment: if you need to add it inside an element but not in the end, you can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: ok, got it. But why is "value" attached to the last two selections? Is it because it's the name of the value? I would just like to retrieve the full text in the option.

Comment: Not able to understand properly. Can you elaborate

Comment: oh wait, insertAdjacentHTML?

Comment: for full option text you should use ".text" as in "comicTeamSelect.options[comicTeamSelect.selectedIndex].text;"

Comment: got it! LGSon, I'm reading the contents of the link, but I don't fully understand it. Could you explain what it does in layman's terms for me?

Comment: the one you are using, "appendChild", always adds the new content at the end of the flow, after all existing elements, with "insertAdjacentHTML" you can chose where to insert it, like before or after an element of your choise

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows 3 options to insert an element: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Ezj/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could get the values from the menus and push them into an array that is then returned? Would help to see what you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can traverse the DOM structure like this:

```
var p1 = $(this).parent(); // first parent
var text1 = p1.text();
var p2 = p1.parent();      // second parent
var text2 = p2.text();
```

Comment: I can't use jquery or innerHTML though.

Comment: is there no way to do it in javascript?

Comment: innerHTML is vanilla javascript and you have just said that you can't use that

Comment: I think I meant I can't use the .innerHTML method

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to fetch your DOM elements and then get the selected values of each, then build your string:

```
function printStuff() {
  var company = document.getElementById("myCompanies").value;
  var team = document.getElementById("myTeams").value;
  var hero = document.getElementById("myHeroes").value;
  
  var str = "You chose " + company + " which is a company, ";
  str += "which owns " + team + " and has the hero" + hero;
  
  //Use the method shown in the above answer
  //Fetch an existing element
  var hook = document.getElementById("myHookElement");
  
  //Create a text node
  var text = document.createTextNode(str);
  
  //Append the text node to the existing element
  hook.appendChild(text);
}
```

You could then call the function once the final drop-down value has been selected.
If you don't know the DOM element names ahead of time, we could traverse the DOM tree or use some type of xpath selector but this may be more expensive in terms of performance.

[DOM XPath Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)

Comment: how would I print that out onto the form though?

Comment: How could this possibly work? You are fetching elements this way, not their value.

Comment: updated the code to fetch the value -- thanks Matúš!

Comment: Hey Daniel, what do you mean by print on the form? just print on the webpage or print to specific textbox on the form?

Comment: same as the method shown in the other answer via createTextNode, however this is simpler for value selection.